# GetRequest rally limit pageSize

Tags: java, rest, rally

Trying to get Results from Rally using GetRequest class but the limit of the pageSize is 20 thereby limiting the result retrieved.

I am using Java to get the details. Is there any method that I can use to set PageSize or limit.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean QueryRequest?  GetRequest is for just reading a single object.

QueryRequest has a setPageSize method which accepts a value between 1 and 2000 as long as you're using WSAPI version 2.0.

You can also use the setLimit method and it will automatically page the results for you if there are multiple pages of data.

```
//Read up to 5000 records, in pages of 1000
queryRequest.setPageSize(1000);
queryRequest.setLimit(5000);
```

Javadocs: http://rallytools.github.io/RallyRestToolkitForJava/

Comment: In GetRequest, is it possible to set pageSize?

Comment: No, because GetRequest is just used to read a single object so there is no need for a page size.  What are you trying to do?  It seems like QueryRequest will be what you want to use...

Comment: I am trying to get revisions (_ref link) through GetRequest. This returns a json object which displays only 20 revision as pageSize is 20

Comment: As I said before, you want to use QueryRequest to get multiple results.  GetRequest just reads a single object.  setPageSize on a QueryRequest as shown above should work for you.  2000 is the max.

Comment: Is it possible to get _ref using QueryRequest?

Comment: The _ref field is always returned on all wsapi results.  Are you not seeing that?

Comment: It may be worth asking a new question rather than trying to hijack this question's comment thread... Thanks!